# Problema con FK en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Soy un tanto nuevo en el diseño de base de datos y me surge la siguiente duda:
Tengo creada una bd llamada "nuevadb" en la cual cree dos tablas (alumno y asignatura) con las siguientes columnas:

---

### **Tabla alumno**

```
Field               Type    Null    Key     Default Extra
codigo_alumno       int(11) NO      PRI     NULL    auto_increment
nombre              text    NO      NULL    
materia_inscripto   int(11) NO      UNI     NULL
```

---

### **Tabla asignatura**

```
Field               Type    Null    Key     Default Extra
codigo_asignatura   int(11) NO      PRI     NULL    auto_increment
nombre_asignatura   text    NO      NULL    
numero              int(11) NO      MUL     NULL
```

Quisiera poder agregar una FK que me permitiese relacionar la columna 'materia_inscripto' de la tabla 'alumno' con la columna 'numero' de la tabla asignatura.
El hecho es que trabajando con MySQL (motor InnoDB) no me lo permite:

> ALTER TABLE `alumno` ADD  FOREIGN KEY (`materia_inscripto`) REFERENCES
>   `asignatura`(`numero`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE; MySQL ha
>   dicho: Documentación
>
> ## 1215 - Unknown error 1215

Más raro aún (por lo menos, con mi desconocimiento del tema) es que si me lo permite si no modifico los "ON UPDATE" y "ON DELETE":

> Su consulta se ejecutó con éxito. ALTER TABLE `alumno` ADD FOREIGN KEY
>   (`materia_inscripto`) REFERENCES `asignatura`(`numero`) ON DELETE
>   RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;

Desde ya agradezco toda la ayuda que me puedan brindar. He consultado varias páginas dentro del sitio y no creo que ninguna encuadre con la misma duda que tengo (varias se resolvían al aplicar el mismo tipo de cotejamiento a las tablas, otras con el mismo tipo de dato [en mi caso, todo es igual: todo a utf8 y los campos relacionados son enteros sin signo]).

### Nota

Si se me olvidó especificar algún dato más que se crea relevante, estoy atento a poder explicitarlo luego :). Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recreé tu base de datos y así lo he logrado:

1. Creo un `index` en la tabla `asignatura` para el campo número:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE `prueba`.`asignatura` 
   ADD INDEX `indexNumero` (`numero` ASC);
   ```
2. Creo un `index` en la tabla `alumno` para el campo `materia_inscripto`:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE `prueba`.`alumno` 
   ADD UNIQUE INDEX `indexinscripto` (`materia_inscripto` ASC);
   ```
3. Creo la llave:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE `prueba`.`alumno` 
   ADD CONSTRAINT `FKinscripto`
       FOREIGN KEY (`materia_inscripto`)
       REFERENCES `prueba`.`asignatura` (`numero`)
       ON DELETE NO ACTION
       ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
   ```

Espero te sirva, y te recomendaría que usaras MySQL Workbench, para hacerte las tareas un poco mas fáciles.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que es porque tu columna codigo_alumno  permite valores nulos y segun entiendo eso no debe de ser.
Es decir por DEFAULT no puede ser null un campo primario